# What is the relationship between the Windows shell file properties and OOXML tags?

Tags: shell, metadata, windows-11, file-properties

I recently posted a Q&A, [*What are the file properties in the Windows 11 shell?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78068319/what-are-the-file-properties-in-the-windows-11-shell), in which I listed all 310 shell file properties. Mysteriously, two weeks later, that number declined to 308. I also report there that the 308 property names are the same as the 308 column names available in File Explorer's column selector.

On the website for the metadata software, [*ExifTool*](https://www.ExifTool.org), in the table of [*Supported File Types*](https://exiftool.org/#supported), the MS Office file types docx, pptx, and xlsx link to a page on [*OOXML Tags*](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/OOXML.html) of the Office Open XML (OOXML) format. This is a long lost of properties, and it’s not the same as the Windows shell properties. We shouldn't expect the lists to be the same because the tags are metadata (i.e., in the file), but the shell properties are not all in the file. But the shell properties include metadata that are not in the list of tags (e.g., `Title`, `Subject`, `Comments`, and `Copyright`) and vice versa (e.g., `Lines`, `Pages`, `Words`).

Obviously, MS Word files have both the properties `Title` and `Words`, yet these properties are included in either the shell properties or the OOXML tags, not both. How is this possible?

What's going on here? What is the relationship between the Windows shell file properties and the OOXML tags? Where does one have to look to get a real, valid list of all the file properties, including but not limited to all the metadata?